# Sharepoint 2013: Site Feed Users Post Count

Tags: sitefeed

Am creating a custom wp to count users post on site feed but cant find the list source.

Will basic CAML and item count will do?

```
SPList spl3 = site.Lists["SiteFeedName"];
SPQuery query3 = new SPQuery();
query3.Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' /><Value Type='Text'>" + login_name() + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
SPListItemCollection items = spl3.GetItems(query3);
intmpa_score = items.Count;
```

Is there a way doing this?

TIA.

Comment: Post you code, so far what you have tried.

Comment: One thing, you have no row limit set in your query so you will definately not get all items.

Comment: The "SiteFeedName" virtually don't exist and was trying to find what list name to use. Before going further I need to know the site feed list / library source.